# Saving to text, receiving error message

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save the contents of a listview box with following code

```
Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
Private Sub Button6_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    W = New IO.StreamWriter("c:\" & "sname" & ".txt")
    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(ListView1.Items(i))
    Next
    W.Close()
End Sub
```

when i try and run the app it is showing a code saying : `Access to the path 'c:\sname.txt' is denied.`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't create file in C: root .. in VB.Net

Comment: Its a more general than that, only admin users get access to root by default in vista or later, even then they UAC permission. However that is the problem, use relative paths instead.

Comment: Under Win Vista, 7, 8 C: is protected by UAC, use another path (e.g. ask it or %temp%)

Comment: Also dispose you streamwriter when your done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows Vista, 7, 8 the root path `C:` is protected by [`UAC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and only accessible in write by admin users; you must run your program as admin or use another path (e.g. asking it or %temp%).

Answer (score 1):

Due to **User Access Control** you really can't create any .txt file directly under C drive, as described all other users.

What you can do is you can create a folder in C drive and save your .txt file inside it.

```
Dim W As IO.StreamWriter
Private Sub Button6_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    W = New IO.StreamWriter("c:\SomeFolderName" & "sname" & ".txt")
    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(ListView1.Items(i))
    Next
    W.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a file in the root of a disk (In this case c:) due to an UAC issue only admin users can write into it. You should either, run your .exe with admin rights or save the file in other location.

Finally, close your `StreamWriter` when you finish writing to the file.

Comment: th OP is closing the streamwriter

Comment: It wasn't closed when I commented :P